# Floor division using Gekko

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

In this optimization problem (a single variable simplified version of mine) I have one variable and I am trying to maximize the objective. The answer should be x = 4 with an objfcnval equal to 2 since as x increases these will be the calculations **0** - 0 = 0, **1** - 2 = -1, **2** - 2 = 0, **3** - 2 = 1, **4** - 2 = *2*, **5** - 4 = 1.

Here is the code:

```py
def my_ceiling(elem1, elem2):
    if (elem1 // elem2) == (elem1 / elem2):
        return elem1 / elem2
    else:
        return (elem1 // elem2) + 1


m = gekko.GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.SOLVER = 1

x = m.Var(value=0, lb=0, ub=5, integer=True)

m.Obj((-1) * (x - 2 * my_ceiling(x, 4)))

m.solve(disp=False)

print('Objective: ' + str((-1) * m.options.objfcnval))
```

```py
    if (elem1 // elem2) == (elem1 / elem2):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'GKVariable' and 'int'
```

The problem is that apparently this kind of operation is not supported. How would I go about using Gekko for problems like these?

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from [another discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862885/linear-program-with-ceiling-or-floor-functions/1863895), one way to implement the floor function is to create a new integer variable `y` that is bounded by `x/4 > y >= x/4 + 1e-8`.

```py
import gekko
m = gekko.GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.SOLVER = 1

x = m.Var(value=0, lb=0,ub=5,integer=True)
y = m.Var(lb=0,ub=5,integer=True)

m.Equations([y<x/4,y>=x/4+1e-8])
m.Maximize((x - 2*y))

m.solve(disp=False)

print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
print('Objective: ' + str((-1)*m.options.objfcnval))
```

This produces a solution for `x`, `y`, and the objective function:

```
4.0 1.0
Objective: 2.0
```

This strategy also works if `x` is not an integer variable but Gekko gives a slightly different answer:

```
3.99999996 1.0
Objective: 1.99999996
```

If there is a reliable method, perhaps we should add a `floor` or `ceil` function in gekko that is similar to some of the other functions in the [model building documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html). Could you keep us updated on your testing and what approach works best?

Comment: Thank you for your response however, I have been seeing how I could apply your answer to my actual problem and I cant see how to do that. On my code I have 27 variables, where x[0] through x[2] are affected by what x[11] through x[26] are.

For example, if the sum of x[11] through x[27] is 9, I need x[0] or x[1] or x[3] to be multiplied by ceiling(9, 2) so 5, if the sum is 15 I would need it to be multiplied by 8.

For context, let's say x[0], x[1], x[3] are different types of generators that power improvements in blocks of 2, and x[11] through x[26] are improvements that require power.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way to manage this is to create an additional variable for every time you need to evaluate the ceiling of a variable. A gekko function such as `y = m.ceil(x/2)` may even be better for managing these functions in complex models. Could you add a feature request to gekko on Github if you'd like to see this added? https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues